# Problem with y axis format ( change from 1e+01)

Tags: r

[image]I want to change the format of y axis from 1e+01.. to 0-200000 breaks( 0, 50000, 1000000, ...200000) in my log plot

```
 p + geom_line(aes(group = state)) + facet_wrap(~ state)+
     geom_point(aes(y = positive), col = "#8B1C62")+
     scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,200000)) + theme_minimal() +
     scale_y_log10()
```

Also I get this error message

```
Scale for 'y' is already present. Adding another scale for 'y', which will replace the existing scale.
```

I don't know what to do. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Scale for 'y' is already present. Adding another scale for 'y', which will replace the existing scale.

This is not an error but a warning. `scale_y_log` is overwriting the parameters you define in `scale_y_continuous`.

To fix a log scale, you can use `coord_trans` and change the limits using `ylim` (untested solution)

```r
 p + geom_line(aes(group = state)) + facet_wrap(~ state)+
     geom_point(aes(y = positive), col = "#8B1C62")+
     theme_minimal() +
     scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 200000, by = 50000)) +
     coord_trans(y = “log10”, ylim = c(0,200000))
```

**Edit**: I had forgetten the question of axis ticks. You need to use `breaks` argument in `scale_y_continous`. By the way, you can directly set `ylim` in `coord_trans` (cf. [the doc](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/coord_trans.html))

Comment: hi, I  get a plot witn no log transformation with your code :(

Comment: @Ilinog I get this error: Error: unexpected input in:
"     scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 200000, by = 50000)) +
     coord_trans(y = “"

Comment: I found a solution: p + geom_line(aes(group = state)) + facet_wrap(~ state)+
     geom_point(aes(y = positive), col = "#8B1C62")+
     scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,200000)) + theme_minimal() +
     scale_y_log10( breaks=c(0,50000,100000,150000,200000))